# predicting the value of a nominal variable from the value of a ratio scale variable

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, corpus-linguistics

I am doing a corpus study on the influence of subject length on word order choice between SVO and VSO orders. TO calculate that, I am using The Generalized Linear Model glm.
glm(formula = WordOrder ~ Subj.Length, family = binomial, data = data)

I want to make sure whether it is okay to predict the value of a nominal variable (word order) from the value of a ratio scale variable (subject length).

Comment: Yes, just use `predict(my_fit, newdata)` and optionally also specify `se.fit = TRUE` to obtain the standard errors associated with the estimated log odds ratios.

Comment: This is being moved to [stats.se], but they'll probably want to see some data or a clearer example

Comment: When using classification, you can use any type of variable as a predictor (AKA independent variable). It's important that the datatype assigned is accurate, before running the model, as well. Additionally, where the datatype is relevant, typically, you will get an error if you use the wrong type.